Coherent sequence of ultrafilters in iterated forcing extensions
Remember that if $\kappa$ is strongly compact, then any ${<}\kappa$-complete filter extends to a ${<}\kappa$-complete ultrafilter.
Let $\Bbb P_\delta=\langle\Bbb P_\alpha,\dot{\Bbb Q}_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\delta\rangle$ be a ${<}\kappa$-distributive forcing iteration with ${<}\kappa$-support such that for each $\alpha\leq\delta$ we have$$\Vdash_{\Bbb P_\alpha}\text{"$\kappa$ is strongly compact"}$$
and assume that in the $\Bbb P_\delta$-extension there is a chain $\langle U_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\delta\rangle$ with $U_\beta\subseteq U_\alpha$ for $\beta<\alpha$ and each $U_\alpha\subseteq(\mathcal P(\kappa))^{\mathbf V^{\Bbb P_\alpha}}$ is a ${<}\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$ in the $\Bbb P_\alpha$-extension.

Does there always exist an ultrafilter $U\subseteq\mathcal P(\kappa)$ in the $\Bbb P_\delta$-extension such that $U_\alpha\subseteq U$ for each $\alpha\in\delta$?
For finite $\delta$ this is clear, since any ${<}\kappa$-complete ultrafilter from the ground model remains a generating set for a ${<}\kappa$-complete filter in the extension, and $\kappa$ is still strongly compact. So the question is really about limit $\delta$.
Moreover, since $\Bbb P_\delta$ forces $\kappa$ to be strongly compact, we may take any ${<}\kappa$-complete ultrafilter $U$ in the $\Bbb P_\delta$-extension that contains the Frechet filter, and since the Frechet filter is the one from the ground model (by ${<}\kappa$-distributivity), it follows that $\langle U\cap\mathbf V^{\Bbb P_\alpha}\mid \alpha\in\delta\rangle$ is a chain of ultrafilters that all extend to $U$.

In case the answer to (1) is No, can we get a Yes under additional assumptions?
E.g.

if $\Bbb P_\delta$ does not collapse cardinals, or
if $\kappa$ is Laver-indestructibly supercompact and each $\dot{\Bbb Q}_\alpha$ is ${<}\kappa$-directed closed, or
if each $U_\alpha$ is a specific flavour of ultrafilter.



Any references to literature on such generic chains of ${<}\kappa$-complete ultrafilters on uncountable $\kappa$ are welcome as well.

I had a thought on this.  What if at each stage you add a stationary set that is almost contained in every set from some measure on κ?  If κ remains strongly compact, then the nonstationary ideal restricted to this set can be extended to a measure in the extension.  Then repeat.  At limit stages try to show that the special stationary sets you add at each stage have stationary intersection. Starting from an indestructible supercompact, I think this can be done with iterated Levy collapses and the limit stage claim should hold at small cofinalities. I’m not sure if this helps with your goal.

You will get a positive answer if $\delta$ has cofinality bigger than $\kappa$ and the subsets of $\kappa$ are all added individually by some stage, since then the union of the $U_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\delta$ simply will be a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter in the extension.

I believe that the answer is no, using some methods from my old paper:

Hamkins, Joel David, Destruction or preservation as you like it, Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 91, No. 2-3, 191-229 (1998). arXiv:1607.00683,  ZBL0949.03047.

The paper shows how to have a supercompact cardinal $\kappa$, say, that is indestructible by certain kinds of forcing but not others. For example, the methods show that we can have a supercompact cardinal $\kappa$ that is indestructible by any length strictly less than $\kappa$ iteration of adding Cohen subsets to $\kappa$, but not by the length $\kappa^+$-iteration, which will destroy even the $\kappa^+$-supercompactness of $\kappa$.
Thus, we will have that $\kappa$ is $\kappa^+$-supercompact in all the partial extensions $V[G_\alpha]$, but not in the $\kappa^+$th extension $V[G]$. We can now proceed to pick a $\kappa$-complete fine measure $U_\alpha$ on $P_\kappa\kappa^+$ in $V[G_\alpha]$, extending the previous, if possible. If we can proceed through all stages $\alpha<\kappa^+$, then we get a counterexample at $\kappa^+$ since $\kappa$ is not $\kappa^+$-supercompact there. And if things go awry earlier, then this is simply a counterexample at that earlier stage $\delta$.
I believe that one can make this work with measures on $\kappa$ instead of measures on $P_\kappa\kappa^+$, since I think my As You Like It methods will show that measurability also is destroyed by the $\kappa^+$ iteration but not the earlier ones. For this, the situation would be that one runs into a problem strictly before $\kappa^+$ since otherwise the union of the ultrafilters on $\kappa$ in $V[G_\alpha]$ would be an ultrafilter in $V[G]$. So we would have a model $V[G_\delta]$ in which $\kappa$ is actually fully supercompact, but there is a tower of measures on $\kappa$ whose union cannot be contained in any measure on $\kappa$.
